# LUIS REST api returns 400 - Resource not found

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I've an app on LUIS which was working fine until I made few changes to the entities list. I published my app after the changes and LUIS returns 400 state. My other apps using same subscription key from Azure work fine. I tried creating a new app with the same data and the new app also returns 400.

The test panel inside the app also does not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you retrain it after making the entities change?

Comment: Yes I retrained and published it multiple times

Comment: This is a tough one. Mine works ok so the service seems to be working (West US, anyway). Perhaps you can revert back to a previous version of it and try that one?

Comment: I tried that. It used to work in both West US and East US2(I've my subscription key here). But nothing works now not even the test panel

Comment: Yeah, the test panel should always work and it seems really weird that it isn't. Apologies I couldn't help but I'll keep thinking and test stuff.

Comment: I've zeroed in on the issue. The issue looks like due to one of the entities which is a list entity.

Comment: If you want some help on those types of problems, we may need your LUIS project export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have any proposed solution, I rebuilt the list entity which was causing the error. Looks like the issue is due to some encoding while converting from excel to json. If anyone comes across a similar scenario, I would suggest to check your entities first.